# JDBC URL DB2 Encoding characters

Tags: java, sql, db2, spring-batch

Is there a way to set URL encoding to UTF-8 in JDBC for DB2?

> jdbc:db2://../characterEncoding=UTF-8;

I know for MySQL that works but for DB2 it doesn't.

My problem is that I try to send a character (E28093 in ASCII table) but in DB2 this character is converted into an arrow character and this is not correct.

Is there any way to send the right character Or the problem is the DB2 configuration?

The DB2 is the 9.4 version and running in z/OS.

---

SOLVED

I recreated my table and added

> CCSID Unicode

into my table space.
And I created the column with the right subtype.
Link for doc: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/char/src/tpc/db2z_createunicodetable.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is the client-side jdbc driver that performs the codepage conversion, and it is vital to know the client-side jdbc driver type and version when doing problem determination. With type-4 *current* jdbc driver versions you do not specify such details on the connection string.

The codepage conversion details depend on the client-side jdbc driver version and type,  the client-side application code page (locale), and the target table/column CCSID.

It's not possible to comment on your specific conversion because you give zero details, i.e. you need to show the hex code of the character at source, and the CCSID of the target and what hex codes ended up at the target, in addition to the jdbc driver version and type.

With some versions of the type-2 driver it was possible to specify property sendCharInputUTF8=yes/no, to influence where the conversion happened (client-side default, or at server side). Refer to the Db2 documentation for details.

If you are using an old jdbc driver (such as 4.14.xxx) then be aware that there were bugs relating to character conversions which may be relevant, so you should ensure to use the latest jdbc driver from Passport-Advantage or Fix-Central  (e.g 4.23.xx or higher).

Your source character is not 7bit ASCII, but is instead Unicode, and in UTF-8 encoding its three byte hex is 0xE2 0x80 0x93 .  In the target database, verify in SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS the values in columns length,coltype,ccsid. If the column stores UTF-8 values the ccsid column in sysibm.syscolumns may be 1208.
You can SELECT HEX(colname) to see the hex values stored in your target column.

Comment: When giving new facts you should better edit the question. What is the CCSID of the target table/column, its datatype, and what is the hex code that ends up in the column ?

Comment: it is a datatype varchar and the ccsid is utf-8.. but I cant find the hex code(Im using QMF tool but I dont know where to find the code)